# problems to show MarkerView on pie chart when using MPPiechart library

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

MainActivity class code:

```
private float[] yData = {25, 35, 40};
private String[] xData = {"x", "y", "z"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layot);
    mChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.view);


    mainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    mChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    mChart.setMaxAngle(360);
    mChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    mChart.setHoleRadius(2);
    mChart.setRotationAngle(360);
    mChart.setRotationEnabled(false);
    mChart.setHighlightPerTapEnabled(false);
    mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(0);

    ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
            // display msg when value selected
            if (e == null)
                return;

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    xData[e.getXIndex()] + " = " + e.getVal() + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });

    addData();
    MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.marker_layout);

    mChart.setMarkerView(mv);


}

private void addData() {
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<yData.length;i++){
        entries.add(new Entry(yData[i],i));
    }
    PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
    dataset.setSliceSpace(0);
    dataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0;i<xData.length;i++){
        labels.add(xData[i]);
    }
    PieData data = new PieData(labels, dataset); // initialize Piedata
    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.setDescription("Description");
    mChart.animateY(2000);
}
```

and in MyMarkerView class

```
public MyMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);

    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    tvContent.setText("xyz");
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

    if (e instanceof CandleEntry) {

        CandleEntry ce = (CandleEntry) e;

        tvContent.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(ce.getHigh(), 0, true));
    } else {

        tvContent.setText("" + Utils.formatNumber(e.getVal(), 0, true));
    }
}

@Override
public int getXOffset(float xpos) {
    // this will center the marker-view horizontally
    return (getWidth() / 2);
}

@Override
public int getYOffset(float ypos) {
    // this will cause the marker-view to be above the selected value
    return getHeight();
}
```

I am using this code for mark on pie chart but not showing anything on chart. Is there any mistake in my code? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine at first sight.
Maybe just add:

```
mchart.setDrawMarkerViews(true);
```

after attaching your customMarkerView to the chart.